# Can't update Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt

Sorry, there are thousands of posts with apt-get problems due to old repos.  But 14.04 LTS is supposed to be a long term support release.

When we try to install anything, or run "apt-get update" we just get a lot of 404s, e.g:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
```

We tried the following:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
apt-get update
```

But this did not help.  Is there any solution?  We cant upgrade them to a newer version of ubuntu as they are all heavily tested production servers.

Is there a way to manually download the unzip package, and install it locally?

I tried also:

```
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

both of these run, but give "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed" etc.

Interestingly, we have not had this problem on other identical servers.  I have just compared a workign server and a non working server for "apt-get update".

Working 14.04 LTS server:

```
:
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Non working 14.04 LTS server:

```
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

cat /etc/apt/sources.list

good server:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

bad server:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the Internet in general? Could you see if `ping -c1 google.com` works successfully in a terminal?

Comment: Yes, I can ping google.  The server has full internet access, nothing blocked.  if you try the url its using (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) on another machine in a browser, you get a 404

Comment: I noticed that it's trying to fetch `Packages` on the Ubuntu server (which doesn't exist), rather than `Packages.gz` or `Packages.bz2` (which do exist in that folder). I'm not sure how significant this is, but I'm mentioning it in case it's a clue to what's going on. I'll do a little research and see if anyone else has insights.

Comment: If possible, could you please post the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file? You can view it with `gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and edit your post to include its contents. Also, are you behind a proxy at all?

Comment: sources.list posted.  No proxy. both the working server and non-working server are next to each other on the same network.  Very odd!